# Dockerfile - RUN apt-get install -y php5-MODULES is not working anymore -'has no installation candidate'. How to solve it?

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

I have an image php5.6+apache that I am using since 3 weeks ago, when I built it, trough a Dockerfile.

I am using this [base image](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/6677546d599d3980781b520f84d03ecaad291dd1/5.6/jessie/apache/Dockerfile) to start my image from.
Everything was working good, until today when I had to change some variables inside php.ini.

Now when I try to build the image again I am getting this error:

```
Step 5/173 : RUN apt-get install -y php5-common
 ---> Running in 8114082e9931
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package php5-common is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-common' has no installation candidate
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y php5-common' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

It seems that it is being happening for each php-module that I try to install.

Here is part of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5-apache

## Update apt-get
RUN apt-get update

RUN php -m    
RUN php -v


RUN apt-get install -y php5-common
RUN apt-get install -y php-calendar
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
RUN apt-get install -y php5-mhash
RUN apt-get install -y php5-intl
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/intl.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/intl.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/intl.so
RUN apt-get install -y php5-mcrypt
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mcrypt.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mcrypt.so
RUN apt-get install -y php5-redis
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/redis.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/redis.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/redis.so
RUN apt-get install -y php5-mysql
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mysql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mysql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mysql.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
RUN apt-get install -y php5-gd
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/gd.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gd.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/gd.so
RUN apt-get install -y php5-gdcm
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/gdcm.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gdcm.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/gdcm.so
RUN apt-get install -y php5-vtkgdcm
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/vtkgdcm.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/vtkgdcm.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/vtkgdcm.so
RUN apt-get install -y php5-ldap
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/ldap.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/ldap.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/ldap.so
RUN apt-get install -y php5-xsl
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/xsl.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/xsl.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xsl.so
RUN apt-get install -y php5-tidy
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/tidy.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/tidy.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/tidy.so
RUN apt-get install -y php5-xmlrpc
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/xmlrpc.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/xmlrpc.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xmlrpc.so
RUN apt-get install -y php5-pgsql
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pgsql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pgsql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pgsql.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/mysqli.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/mysqli.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mysqli.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_mysql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_mysql.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/pdo_pgsql.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pdo_pgsql.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/pdo_pgsql.so
RUN cp /etc/php5/mods-available/readline.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d && ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20131226/readline.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/readline.so

#COPYING__php.ini
RUN cp /etc/php5/cli/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
RUN ls -l /usr/local/etc/


## Setting up php.ini varaibles
RUN grep '^post_max_size' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN sed -i 's,^post_max_size =.*$,post_max_size = 2048M,' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN grep '^post_max_size' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

RUN grep '^upload_max_filesize' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN sed -i 's,^upload_max_filesize =.*$,upload_max_filesize = 2048M,' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN grep '^upload_max_filesize' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

...
```

Basically `has no installation candidate` error for all Modules that was working 3 weeks ago.

How could I solve that?

## UPDATE

To follow the issue see this [POST](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/551)

Comment: To begin, group your RUNs, because your `apt-get update` is forgotten when you try to install

Answer (score 1):

The official PHP container image comes with helpers to make this easier. These examples come directly from [the PHP repository on Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/).

To install the core extension `mcyrpt` you would add the following to your `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mcrypt
```

Some extensions require libraries exist on the system (because the extension is compiled when you build your container). Note that in this example, all of the commands are strung together, you *could* issue each as an individual `RUN`.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev \
      libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
      libmcrypt-dev \
      libpng-dev
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

For PECL extensions, like `redis` or `memcached` you'll let `pecl install` handle the install and then use `docker-php-ext-enable` to add the appropriate `.ini` file(s). Not unlike the `gd` example above, some PECL extensions have their own dependencies, so you'd use `apt-get install -y ...` to add those before installing.

```
RUN pecl install redis-3.1.0 && docker-php-ext-enable redis
```

Stringing it all together, it might look something like this to add `gd`, `redis` and `mcrypt`.

```
FROM php:5-apache 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev \
      libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
      libmcrypt-dev \
      libpng-dev
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mcrypt
RUN pecl install redis-3.1.0 && docker-php-ext-enable redis

RUN php -m
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `Dockerfile` you provided the [link](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/6677546d599d3980781b520f84d03ecaad291dd1/5.6/jessie/apache/Dockerfile) to, it has these lines:

```
# prevent Debian's PHP packages from being installed
# https://github.com/docker-library/php/pull/542
RUN set -eux; \
    { \
        echo 'Package: php*'; \
        echo 'Pin: release *'; \
        echo 'Pin-Priority: -1'; \
    } > /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-debian-php
```

Preference of `-1` for `Pin-Priority` for PHP packages is telling the system do NOT install these packages. 
  And the pull request is explaining why https://github.com/docker-library/php/pull/542.

To solve your problem you have to use their way of installing PHP packages using the build-in `docker-php-ext-install` command. Here is the example from their official  page https://hub.docker.com/_/php/:

```
FROM php:5-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

Good luck.